# How to get the rest of the combinations forms of 9 choose 4?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 9 digits, I need to figure out the 126 possibilities of 9 choose 4, if we considered that 5 digits equal to 1 (at 4 digits equal to 0).

Example:

```
000011111
000101111
000110111
000111011
000111101
000111110
001001111
001010111
001011011
001011101
001011110
001100111
001101011
001101101
001101110
001110011
001110101
001110110
001111001
001111010
001111100
010001111
010010111
010011011
010011101
010011110
010100111
010101011
010101101
010101110
010110011
010110101
010110110
010111001
010111010
010111100
011000111
011001011
011001101
011001110
011010011
011010101
011010110
011011001
011011010
011011100
011100011
011100101
011100110
011101001
011101010
011101100
011110001
011110010
011110100
011111000
100001111
100010111
100011011
100011101
100011110
100100111
100101101
100101110
100110011
100110101
100110110
100111001
100111010
100111100
101000111
101001101
101001110
101011001
101011010
101011100
101100011
101100101
101100110
101101001
101101010
101101100
101110001
101110010
101110100
101111000
110000111
110001011
110001101
110001110
110010011
110010101
110010110
110011001
110011010
110011100
110100011
110100101
110100110
110101001
110101010
110101100
110110001
110110010
110110100
110111000
111000011
111000101
111000110
111001001
111001010
111001100
111010001
111010010
111010100
111011000
111100001
111100010
111100100
111101000
111110000
```

These were the 121 forms, I tried hard to get the rest, How could I do that? What is the 5 forms left!?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "out of $9$ ones" and "out of $9$ digits of number one". In the example there are only $5$ digits$~1$ each time. Given that $126=\binom95$ one may assume you meant $5$ digits equal to$~1$ (at $4$ digits equal to$~0$).

Comment: Yes, I meant that `meant 5 digits equal to 1 (at 4 digits equal to 0). ` I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one systematic method to generate all combinations (examples of new generated sequences are bolded):

1) Start with **000011111**.

2) If the rightmost 0 is not the last digit of the sequence, switch its place with the 1 at its right (e.x.: 000011111->**000101111**). Repeat this step until 0 is the last digit of the sequence.

3) If the rightmost 0 is the last digit of the sequence, then go back to the beginning sequence (000011111), and move the two rightmost 0's one step towards the right (e.x.: 000011111->**001001111**).

4) Repeat Step 2 until 0 is the last digit of the sequence. Then, repeat Step 3, except go back to the product of the latest instance of Step 3 instead of the beginning sequence, then move the two rightmost 0's one step towards the right (e.x.: 001001111->**001100111**).

5) Keep repeating Step 2-4 until 00 are the last two digits of the sequence. Then, go back to the beginning sequence (000011111), and move the three rightmost 0's one step towards the right (e.x.: 000011111->**010001111**).

6) Repeat Steps 2-5 appropriately until 000 are the last three digits of the sequence. Then, go back to the beginning sequence (000011111), and move all 0's one step towards the right (e.x.: 000011111->**100001111**). This is the new beginning sequence corresponding to 000011111.

7) Repeat Steps 2-6 with regards to the sequence generated in Step 6 (i.e.: instead of going back to 000011111, go back to the sequence generated by the latest instance of Step 6).

The final sequence generated will be 111110000, at the time of which this algorithm will not be able to proceed; this indicates that we've finished generating all possible combinations.

Comment: Long way, hah :) Thank you any way, I'll try it.

Comment: The example in step 3 does not match its condition. Also this description only superficially resembles an algorithm; its interpretation is probematic. For instance is step 5 says "keep repeating step 2-4", then at what step are we while doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Often a systematic way of enumerating a combinatorial set can be given by choosing a total ordering, and describing the least element and how to find the next element (unless one is at the last one). Here the elements are already naturally ordered by interpreting them as numbers (binary if you like, it makes no difference), and $00011111$ is the least one.

To find the next element given any such number (except $111110000$, the last), find the position$~i$ of the rightmost digit $0$ that has at least one digit $1$ to it right. The string from digit $i+1$ to the end will consist of one or more digits$~1$ followed by zero or more digits$~0$; it is the largest number that can be made of these digits. Therefore increasing our number will require modifying either digit$~i$ or a digit further to the left; we will in fact change digit$~i$ from$~0$ to$~1$, and do further changes to its right so as to produce the smallest possible increase. This is done by permuting the $01$ at positions $i,i+1$ to become$~10$, and moving any trailing zeros in the number leftwards to positions $i+2$ and following (any digits$~1$ moved across are pushed to the end of the number).

This procedure is easy to implement: search from the right for a digit$~1$ while counting the $k\geq0$ digits$~0$ skipped, search further for a digit$~0$ while counting the $l\geq1$ digits$~1$ skipped; this gives position$~i$, from which one writes a digit$~1$, then $k+1$ digits$~0$, then $l-1$ digits$~1$. When $k$ equals the total number of digits$~0$, the final permutation of the digits has been reached and one stops.